# Image generated by PHP not cached

Tags: php

I generate some picture with PHP, and those picture are not cached by the browser.

I ouput some picture through a php file the url looks like this :

http://127.0.0.1:8080/workspace/cps/index.php?act=file&act2=preview_or_icon&template=disable&file_id=341

in my php file i've :

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
//Read File
```

Comment: For an image (or for that matter, any file) to be cached, it needs to be static. You're generating it on demand each time.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. Are you saying that the page loads slowly because the images aren't cached?

Comment: Generally, the right way to this, is to write the files to disk, serve them from your webserver, and have some sort of a 404 handler/rewrite rule to generate them when they don't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks Tyler yes i was thinking of this as a solution but there is no way to do it without doing this then?

Comment: I don't get what's the real difference between a generated file in php and a real static file, if i use an url rewriting the browser will not see the difference then?

Comment: ok i find the solution to my problem, there is no difference for the browser btw a file generated in php or not!!!! We just have to set the header info corretly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added this:

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,time()+60*60*24*30));
```

And fixed!